# Is there a Microsoft-specific (for Microsoft compiler) data type for floating point numbers

Tags: c, types, floating-point

Is there any specific data type for Microsoft's compiler for representing floating data points. I seem to find only float, double and long double

Comment: Why do you expect to find an MSVC specific one? The existing ones will do nicely.

Comment: It's university task and i have been searching all day long. Even looked MS's compilator extensions and didn't find anything.

Comment: Why do you need another floating point type?

Comment: If you read the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=msvc-160) and there were none, then clearly the answer is no. The only time you would find things not implemented documented as such is if such an implementation was normally required or expected.  You cannot invent a data type, then complain that it is not documented.

Comment: What is the actual task you have been set; it seems likely that you have misunderstood it.  The only Microsoft specific feature with respect to floating point is that `double` and `long double` have the same 64 bit representation.  In that respect it differes from gcc which has various additional floating point types and `long double` is larger then `double` on some targets.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  At time of writing Visual C++ v16 a.k.a Visual C++ 2019, does not support any floating point data types other than those defined in the C and C++ standards.  Moreover unlike GCC on Intel x86/x64 targets, `double` and `long double` have teh same 64-bit representation.

This is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=msvc-160

The Intel x86/x64 FPU supports an 80 bit data type in hardware, but it is not directly supported by a data type.

GCC on the other has a number of extended types https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html including a `__float80` to match the hardware and a `__float128`.  `long double` is not the same as `double` on GCC.

Comment: Re “`long double` is not the same as `double` on GCC”: That is adjustable with options such as `-mlong-double-64`.